# SEARCH THROUGH ROW FOR SPECIFIC VALUE IN ORACLE

Tags: oracle, plsql, querying

I want to search in Table row with 32 columns, in each of one for specific value and count appearance , is it possible to query entire row without typing every column name in oracle ???

Comment: nope. but you can get list of all columns and create the query dynamically

Comment: even for 1 column, you want to search for a value without using column name? how will oracle know what you are searching for ?

Comment: Sounds like a bad data model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible but the solution is not fast, and require basic knowledge about xquery.

prepare test table

```
create table test_objects as select * from user_objects where rownum < 100;

select * from 
     xmltable('for $row in ora:view("test_objects")/ROW return count($row/*[contains(text(),$TO_SEARCH)])' passing 'N' as "TO_SEARCH" columns cnt number path '.');
```

Query counts columns which contain  "N" in value.

if you change a bit a query we can see which columns contain searched value

```
select * from 
     xmltable('for $row in ora:view("test_objects")/ROW return <ROW><CNT>{count($row/*[contains(text(),$TO_SEARCH)])}</CNT><COLUMNS>{string-join($row/*[contains(text(),$TO_SEARCH)]/name(),", " )}</COLUMNS></ROW>' passing 'N' as "TO_SEARCH"
     columns 
     cnt number path 'CNT'
     , list_of_column varchar2(4000) path 'COLUMNS'
     );
```

Comment: This is EXCTLY what i was trying to get.

Comment: Thank you very much Arkadiusz Łukasiewicz 
This is EXCTLY what i was trying to get. 
And i'm not familjar with xmltable , so if i want to add more conditions like "AND USER_ID = (parameter)" OR other parameters is it possible ??

Comment: Yes it is possible. You should find some tutorial about XQuery language or about `XQuery FLWOR`. The second option is very similar to normal sql and it should be clear for you

Answer (score 0):

1. Tested on EMP table, should be available with Oracle DB installation(I guess).
2. Creates a sql text for searching across all fields.
3. Assumes you have access to `DBA_TAB_COLUMNS`, if not try `USER_TAB_COLUMNS`, if you own the table
4. %KING% is the search term.
5. SQL string has a limit of 4000 characters.
6. OWNER of these tables can be different, since you might have the table in a different schema

Below can be run on SQL Plus or the SQL client of your choice :)

```
VARIABLE cur REFCURSOR;

DECLARE
    v_chr VARCHAR2(4000);
    v_chr_tablename VARCHAR2(30) := 'EMP';
    v_chr_searchterm VARCHAR2(100) := 'KING';
BEGIN

    SELECT 'SELECT * FROM ' ||  v_chr_tablename || ' where '
        || RTRIM ( XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT (E, 'TO_CHAR('
        ||column_name
        || ')', ' || ').EXTRACT ( '//text()')
    ORDER BY column_name).getStringVal (), ' || ')
        ||' like ''%' || v_chr_searchterm || '%'''
    INTO v_chr
    FROM DBA_TAB_COLUMNS
    WHERE table_name = v_chr_tablename
    AND owner        = 'APPS';

    OPEN :cur FOR v_chr;

END;
/
print cur;
```